# Prepaid nano SIM for an unlocked iPhone in Malta?

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, malta

I'd like to get a local number and data plan for my unlocked US iPhone 5 while I'm in Malta.

Which carriers offer this, and how do I actually get the SIM - just go to a cell phone store and ask for one?

Comment: At the airport, I was able to go to the Vodafone shop and get a nano SIM for an iPhone 6. The girl at the shop even set it up for me. Spent 20 euros, 10 for 1GB data the other 10 for anything else.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g190311-i348-k4408693-Prepaid_SIMcard_for_mobile_surf_on_IPhone-Malta.html) is a topic on some forum about buying pre-paid on Malta. You can buy sim card by [vodafone](https://www.vodafone.com.mt/prepaidplans) or by [GO mobile](http://www.go.com.mt/). It costs about 10 EUR. They said that Go Mobile has even shop at the airport, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 main mobile providers in Malta.

- [Melita](http://www.melita.com/)
- [Vodafone](https://www.vodafone.com.mt/)
- [GO](http://www.go.com.mt/)

You simply go to any of their store and ask for it.  GO have a shop at the airport, but all of them have shops littered around malta or sub-agents.  Vodafone have just introduced a 4G (LTE) network, so if you're interested in the fastest internet I think that would be the best.  You can get both pre-paid and post-paid from all of the providers.